# Best way to run a delayed job in browser

Tags: mapreduce, sinatra, delayed-job, riak

I  have to develop an API which does some map reduce jobs in the background and then  return the results. Its a sinatra application with a Riak No-sql database. The issue is that the job takes around 5-10 minutes to run. And the request times out in that amount of time. What can be the best ways to run such kind of jobs in the background?

Comment: Is the data set large enough (data to be analyzed won't fit in RAM) that you really need MapReduce, or are you using that as a way to query for arbitrary data in Riak?

It's far better to model your data appropriately for key/value than to rely on MapReduce for everything; as you note, MapReduce is better suited for batch jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like DelayedJob with a layer of something like Redis over the top (to keep track of job state), that is accessed by a unique route (your Sinatra API). Then have a different page (the web page for browser clients) that calls the API via AJAX, polling it periodically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the operation system scheduler

[windows task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Its a ruby app, running on a mac machine.